# Apache/WSGI process dying

Tags: python, django, apache, permissions, mod-wsgi

I recently have changed the server for some Django/Python sites and immediately I got into trouble. My Apache instance or the WSGI daemon simply dies! No logs, no warnings or errors. I have to restart the Apache as root and I'm thinking is a serious permissions flaw somewhere. My Linux knowlegde is limited and aparently I'm the only one who had this problem, because I cannot relate to other answers I've found so far.

The WSGI version is 3.3 (`multiprocess = True` and `multithread = True`), Python 2.7 and Django 1.4 on a Debian machine. Some of the python libraries I needed, Django included, didn't come from the Debian's repository; I had them installed "manually".

Sometimes, I dont know if it is important or not, I get this error:

> "ImportError: Failed to import _strptime because the import lockis
>   held by another thread."

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but you could look into using supervisord to restart it automatically until you find the proper solution http://supervisord.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/frequently-asked-questions.html#apache-process-crashes
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html

Make sure you are not loading mod_python at same time.

Ensure you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode and not embedded mode.

Force application to run in main interpreter application group.

The _strptime issue is a Python bug (only fixed in 3.3). Explicitly `import _strptime` module at the start of the WSGI script file.

Comment: I've read that, but is a little too much for my brain atm!.. Well, I got no choice then, more coffee ... I've end up here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608748/mod-wsgi-process-getting-killed-and-django-stops-working, because I've found this "Script timed out before returning headers", but is not the same problem ... I shall read the documentation again, maybe the mod_wsgi is compiled against a different version of python ...

Comment: The key one to read is http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API and try setting WSGIApplicationGroup as explained.

Comment: the server admin has increased the number of threads and processes ... now it seems stable!